# Is there a more elegant way to check a variable in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have objects and want to check if a certain property exists.

I have nested maps and lists that look like this:

`some.videos.files` (map including a map including a list)

`some` always exists but may be empty.

If I do this:

```
<#if some.videos.files?has_content>
```

and `some.videos` doesn't exist I get an error.

So I do this now:

```
<#if some.videos?has_content && some.videos.files?has_content>
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I know I could do

```
<#if some.videos?? && some.videos.files?has_content>
```

but I don't consider this to be much better especially if you may have deeper nested variables.

Basically I only want to know if `some.videos.files` exists and is not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `(some.videos.files)?has_content`. The same logic works with `??` and `!` too, like `(some.videos.files)??` and `(some.videos.files)![]`.